# Getting exact time-stamp appended to the file from ffmpeg process

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, timestamp, video-streaming

I am trying to capture frames using ffmpeg from a stream of video , which i am saving locally to my folder, 
I need to know the exact time-stamp at which the frame is being captured
what i have tried so far is :

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://ipaddress/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1  -an -vf showinfo %10d.jpg 2> res.txt
```

which i got from the source :
[get-each-frame-time-stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934300/gopro-get-each-frame-time-stamp)

this works fine too, the res.txt contains the time-elapsed of each frame since ffmpeg started(if my understanding is not wrong) ,

What i need is to get this time appended to the image files names which are being created or some other ways so that time-stamp information could be stored within the image.

any kind of help would be really appreciated .

Comment: Please do reply , if this question seems out-of the box . that is i am totally trying to sail the wrong ship

Comment: You can use [strftime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473627/how-to-add-the-timestamp-as-a-part-of-the-generated-image-file-name-in-ffmpeg/33476307#33476307) but it doesn't have the necessary resolution.